# Trouble with jenkinsfile and docker

Tags: image, docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

How do you do? Hope you are doing fine :) I've encountered a lil' problem regarding a Jenkinsfile....
The thing is, I want to override the docker entrypoint.
Whenever I try to run:

`"docker run -it --rm --entrypoint="sh" docker.image.com:dev" >> this works`

BUT!! when I do it before the image:

`docker run -it --rm docker.img.com:dev --entrypoint="sh" >> doesn't work :(`

And, in the jenkinsfile, i need this image to have it's entrypoint overriden (the default entrypoint is some "java -Xmx2G file.jar"

Jenkinsfile snippet:

```
agent {
        docker {
          reuseNode true
          image 'img.docker.com:dev'
          args '--entrypoint=sh'
        }
      }
```

This returns the following error:

"[...] docker top c51a2d1e255302db1e20916a8698237d3a8cc1f470915d619f781a9085d8b99b -eo pid,comm
ERROR: The container started but didn't run the expected command. Please double check your ENTRYPOINT does execute the command passed as docker run argument[...]"

And Jenkins does some sort of "docker run docker.img.com:dev cat".
Is there a way so i can put the entrypoint before the image???
Thanks
E

Comment: Can you restructure your Dockerfile to not require overriding `ENTRYPOINT`?  Make the primary command be `CMD`, and either omit `ENTRYPOINT` entirely or make it be a wrapper script that does first-time setup and then `exec "$@"` to launch the `CMD`.

Comment: (In between your two `docker run` commands, anything before the image name is Docker arguments and anything after it is the command to run, which is why that ordering makes a difference.)

Comment: Thanks @DavidMaze, I solved it by splitting the entrypoint and the cmd. The entrypoint was the "java -jar jarfile.jar" and the CMD was all the flags that came along the program. Then I could just override the cmd settings in jenkins

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @DavidMaze, I solved it by splitting the entrypoint and the cmd. The entrypoint was the "java -jar jarfile.jar" and the CMD was all the flags that came along the program. Then I could just override the cmd settings in jenkins